Return all terminal children in VBA
I have a tree defined in two columns, a parent and a child column.
For example, the table might be as follows:



Parent
Child




A
A1


A
A2


A1
A1.1


A1
A1.2


A1
A1.3


A2
A2.1


A1.2
A1.2.1


A1.2
A1.2.2



Given a node, I need all terminal children of that node. In the example above, given node A1, I need the list {A1.1, A1.2.1, A1.2.2, A1.3}.
I have tried the following code. I iterate through the parent column to find a match. If matched, I recursively find through the children nodes.
I think it's close but it's giving me the intermediary children nodes as well as the specified node itself. I can filter out the specified node easily enough (even post the VBA process, so I'm not worried about that). I'm struggling to think through removing the intermediary children nodes, however. Appreciate any help.
Public Function GetChildren(CheckString As String, CheckColumn As Range) As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    For Each Cell In CheckColumn
        Set temp = Cell.Find(CheckString)
        If (Not temp Is Nothing) Then
            Call GetChildren(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2, CheckColumn)
        End If
    Next
    
    Debug.Print (CheckString)
        
End Function


Sub Main()

Dim CheckColumn As Range
Dim CheckTable As String
Dim CheckString As String

CheckString = "E2270"
Set CheckColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Map").Range("CheckRange")

Call GetChildren(CheckString, CheckColumn)

End Sub


This will be implemented on a list of a few hundred parent nodes. I need to traverse the parent nodes and, for each, list out the associated terminal children nodes. I am not constrained by how that output looks, only how it performs. Example output might be as follows:



Parent
Terminal 1
Terminal 2
Terminal 3
Terminal 4




A1
A1.1
A1.2.1
A1.2.2
A1.3


A2
A2.1






An alternative output could be the following:



Parent
Terminal Children




A1
A1.1, A1.2.1, A1.2.2, A1.3


A2
A2.1





Use Dict object to store parent-child relation

Microsoft documentation:

Collection object


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub GetTerminalNodes()
    Dim i As Long, objDic As Object
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim sParent As String, sChild As String
    Const START_NODE = "A1"  ' modify as needed
    ' load data into an array
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load parent-child into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sParent = arrData(i, 1): sChild = arrData(i, 2)
        If Not objDic.exists(sParent) Then
            Set objDic(sParent) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        End If
        objDic(sParent)(sChild) = ""
    Next i
    Dim oCol As New Collection, vItem
    ' get the terminal nodes
    GetNodes objDic, START_NODE, oCol
    ' write to Immediate Window
    If oCol.Count > 0 Then
        For Each vItem In oCol
            Debug.Print vItem
        Next
    End If
End Sub
' recursive get the child node
Sub GetNodes(oDic As Object, ByVal sPar As String, ByRef oCol As Collection)
    Dim vKey
    If oDic.exists(sPar) Then
        For Each vKey In oDic(sPar)
           GetNodes oDic, vKey, oCol
        Next
    Else
        oCol.Add sPar
    End If
End Sub

Output:
    A1.1
    A1.2.1
    A1.2.2
    A1.3


Update:
Option Explicit

Sub GetTerminalNodes()
    Dim i As Long, iR As Long, objDic As Object
    Dim arrData, rngData As range, arrRes(), vKey, vItem
    Dim sParent As String, sChild As String
    Const START_NODE = "A1"  ' modify as needed
    ' load data into an array
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load parent-child into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sParent = arrData(i, 1): sChild = arrData(i, 2)
        If Not objDic.exists(sParent) Then
            Set objDic(sParent) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        End If
        objDic(sParent)(sChild) = ""
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(objDic.count, 1)
    arrRes(0, 0) = "Parent"
    arrRes(0, 1) = "Terminal Children"
    Dim oCol As New Collection
    For Each vKey In objDic.Keys
        If InStr(vKey, ".") = 0 Then
            Set oCol = Nothing
            ' get the terminal nodes
            GetNodes objDic, vKey, oCol
            ' write to Immediate Window
            If oCol.count > 0 Then
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = vKey
                For Each vItem In oCol
                    arrRes(iR, 1) = arrRes(iR, 1) & "," & vItem
                Next
                arrRes(iR, 1) = Mid(arrRes(iR, 1), 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Sheets.Add
    range("A1").Resize(iR + 1, 2).value = arrRes
End Sub
' recursive get the child node
Sub GetNodes(oDic As Object, ByVal sPar As String, ByRef oCol As Collection)
    Dim vKey
    If oDic.exists(sPar) Then
        For Each vKey In oDic(sPar)
           GetNodes oDic, vKey, oCol
        Next
    Else
        oCol.Add sPar
    End If
End Sub



Thanks, this is helpful and does look to be working. My end goal is to output the list of terminal nodes to Excel. The form of that output isn't really important (e.g., one found node per cell vs. a concatenated list of all nodes in one cell, etc.), but I need to run the search for a few hundred parent nodes. I'm finding that looping through the collection to output each item to a cell is quite slow. Do you have recommendations on this? I'm wondering if there is a way to bundle the finding of the terminal node with the output to increase speed or if possible to avoid collections entirely.

Please edit your post to share the expected output.

Fine solution; fyi you might be interested in an alternative approach with an integrated sort routine :-)

@taller I have edited to include expected output.

I've updated the code.
What should I do when someone answers my question?
What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?

Alternative with integrated sorting routine
As an alternative to @taller 's dictionary approach I demonstrate a solution via Application.Match(), negative filtering and a tricky BubbleSort routine allowing to compare sortable code values.
In order to get to a quick result I assign data arrays and check all matches of all indicated child codes within a parents code array (cf. section c))

case 1: a numeric match value indicates a finding of preceding nodes, the element has to be neglected (removed)
case 2: a non-numeric(here:error) value indicates that a last child has been found, the element is valid.

As I loop child elements without recursion, I sort the result by a BubbleSort function (including a reformatting part to allow sorting actually comparable code elements).
Example with 2-digit-tokens: `"A17.11.3"` would result into `"A17.11.03"` and allows comparison against e.g. "A17.1.3" ~> "A7.01.03". 

Sub LastChild()
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78460728/return-all-terminal-children-in-vba
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
 
    Const DELETE As String = "X"
    With Sheet1         ' or: With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Map")
    'a) get lastRow
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'b) get data
        Dim parents:  parents = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value2
        Dim children: children = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Value2
    'c) check if child is last child via Match()
        '1. numeric value indicates a finding of preceding nodes, has to be removed (X)
        '2. a non-numeric(here:error) value indicates that a last child has been found!
        Dim result: ReDim result(1 To UBound(children))
        Dim i As Long, ii As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(children)
            Dim chk
            chk = Application.Match(children(i, 1), parents, 0)
            result(i) = IIf(IsNumeric(chk), DELETE, children(i, 1))
        Next i
    'd) resize & sort result
        result = Filter(result, DELETE, False)  ' remove preceding children ("X") via negative filtering
        BubbleSort result, reformatted:=True    ' sort result by comparing sortable codes
        Debug.Print Join(result, ";")           ' show 1-based 1D result array
    End With
End Sub

Immediate window result:
Side note: Imo code element "A2.1" is a valid result and actual last child missing in your post :-)
    A1.1;A1.2.1;A1.2.2;A1.3;A2.1

If you want to display the result array starting in any target cell you might code as follows:
 Sheet1.Range("D2").Resize(1, UBound(result)) = result  ' horizontal
'Sheet1.Range("D2").Resize(Ubound(result), 1) = result  ' vertical 

EDIT due to comment: If you need to indicate the corresponding parent you might want to use another function, example call: Sheet1.[C2] = getParent("A1.2.2") resulting in "A1.2". You can adapt this easily in any direction to meet your additional requirements.
Function getParent(ByVal code As String) As String
    Const delim As String = "."
    Dim tmp As Variant: tmp = Split(code, delim)
    ReDim Preserve tmp(UBound(tmp) - 1)
    getParent = Join(tmp, delim)
End Function


Sorting routines (including reformatting)
Sub BubbleSort(arr, Optional ByVal reformatted As Boolean = False)
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
    Dim cnt As Long, nxt As Long, temp
'A) sort elements (here: code numbers) made sortable by reformatting
    If reformatted Then
        For cnt = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
            For nxt = cnt + 1 To UBound(arr)
                If refmt(arr(cnt)) > refmt(arr(nxt)) Then   ' << compare reformated values
                    temp = arr(cnt)
                    arr(cnt) = arr(nxt)
                    arr(nxt) = temp
                End If
            Next nxt
        Next cnt
'B) sort elements without any intermediate reformatting (=default)
    Else
        For cnt = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
            For nxt = cnt + 1 To UBound(arr)
                If arr(cnt) > arr(nxt) Then                 ' << compare original values
                    temp = arr(cnt)
                    arr(cnt) = arr(nxt)
                    arr(nxt) = temp
                End If
            Next nxt
        Next cnt
    End If
End Sub

Function refmt(ByVal code, Optional ByVal digits As Long = 2) As String
'Purp:  reformat delimited codes like "A17.1.3" to "A17.01.03" to make them sortable
'Auth:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
        Const DELIM As String = "."
        Dim letter As String: letter = Left(code, 1)    ' assuming one start letter
        Dim tmp: tmp = Split(Mid(code, 2), DELIM)
        Dim ii As Long
        For ii = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
            tmp(ii) = Format(CInt(tmp(ii)), String(digits, "0"))
        Next ii
        refmt = letter & Join(tmp, DELIM)               ' join to entire string element
End Function

